# Ng build --prod

Tags: nodejs, angular

Hola cuando ejecuto el

```
ng build --prod
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje

```
/usr/bin/ng: línea 40: exec: build: no se encontró
```

Comment: Intenta con `ng build --env=prod` o con `ng build --target=production`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bueno despues de pasar un rato buscando. Decidi reinstalar el @angular/cli. Para ello utilize estos comandos

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli

ng-v
```

Una vez reinstalado fui capaz de utilizar el ng build --prod

Answer (score 3):

El argumento --prod ya no tiene soporte, ahora es así:

```
ng build --configuration production --aot
```

Para más información mira: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularcli